# why hibernate no update field?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, field

I'm updating field in `Hibernate` to Oracle database, but it doesn't. Why `Hibernate` doesn't update field `Leido`?

```
    if (mensajeId.getLeido().equals("false")) { 
        Transaction tx = Main.getSesion().beginTransaction();
        mensajeId.setLeido("true");
        Mensaje mensaje = listaMensajesRecibidos.getSelectedValue();
        mensaje.setId(mensajeId);
        mensaje.setUsuarioByEmisor(mensaje.getUsuarioByEmisor());
        mensaje.setUsuarioByReceptor(mensaje.getUsuarioByReceptor());
        Main.getSesion().update(mensaje);           
        tx.commit();
    }
```

Comment: What does `listaMensajesRecibidos.getSelectedValue()` do? Are you sure it reads data from DB?

Comment: this is a JList that I have in my aplication, it's works well, i think

Comment: What is `mensajeId`. It seems to be a class type, not a mappable native value (like boolean). If it is a class type, how is it mapped, one-to-one ?

Comment: i have a data base with two tables mensaje and usuario. I mapped whith hibernate and it created three classes usuario, mensaje and mensajeid. in mensaje are many field and in mensajeid are others

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to use `update()` method for not managed instance. You should use `saveOrUPdate()` or `save()` in this case.

If however you think that this entity already in you DB but the instance is not connected to your session you should use `merge()` before.

Comment: i test with update, save and saveOrUpdate and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The aswer is tha, if your table haven't got primary key, Hibernate create to you a tableId with several field, and it not possible to modify. You have to create field primary key in your table